# Как оно понимает, какого конкретно Usera доставать из базы?

Tags: firebase

```js
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed_in_user

Как оно понимает, какого конкретно Usera доставать из базы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед использованием firebase.auth().currentUser надо предложить юзеру авторизоваться. Вот здесь написано, как это сделать: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin 
Соответственно, currentUser будет тот, под которым юзер авторизовался или null, если не авторизовался.

Comment: И что каждый раз запрашивать авторизацию? Не понимаю. Каждый раз при заходе на сайт пользователь же не будет авторизироваться

Comment: Нет, конечно. Пользоатель авторизовался, и его учётные данные сохранились на конкретном этом устройстве для конкретного этого приложения. И вот эти учётные данные и достаются.

Comment: Это просходит автоматически? А если у меня web версия?

Comment: Куда оно отправляет?

Comment: Да, это происходит автоматически. Подозреваю, что в веб версии для сохранения сессии используется local storage или cookies.